# EditText input type messes gravity in RTL mode

Tags: android, xml

I'm currently working on a project which needs to support 2 languages (English and Farsi) and Farsi is a right to left language. I provided the application with 2 strings value resources which works fine on showing the right thing. But my problem is whenever I use an input type of "phone" or "textpassword" in xml file, android ignores gravity and pushes the text to left in farsi locale which by default should be right. I even tried `android gravity: start` and it ignored it too. 
here is my activity layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login_screen_alt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginScreen"
    android:background="@drawable/back_main"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintLightColor"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_key"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_login"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintLightColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_number_login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/enter"
        android:theme="@style/loginButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLogin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="@string/register_ad"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I desperately need to use inputType in my project or any way around it.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to set alignment, like :

`android:textAlignment="viewStart"`